# Are there any dumb USB-C to USB-C cables available? Simple 24 to 24 pin cable

Tags: usb

I made the mistake of thinking that the cables were dumb by default and the "smart" electronics were on the boards the cables plugged into.

I designed non USB compliant boards that used USB-C connectors and now my project doesn't work because all cables I find already have some circuitry inside.

Do simple 24 to 24 pin USB connector cables exist and how do I search for them?

Comment: What kind of circuitry was in them?

Comment: I'm making a small sized CSI extender for a raspberry pi camera. Much like this: http://bitwizard.nl/shop/image/cache/catalog/shop_pics/rpi_camera_extension/dsc06436-600x600.jpg or this https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0174/1800/products/2015-04-12T07-15-22.906Z-IMG_0029.JPG.2560x2560_q85_1024x1024.jpg?v=1438330318 , but with a smaller connector/plug.

Comment: I mean in the cables

Comment: Oh sorry, some ends are shorted and I think I have found at least one of the datasheets depicted a capacitor between a pair of terminals.

Comment: Here, I found it: http://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/sd/687980003_sd.pdf

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about electronics inside the Type-C cable overmolds. Cables with electronics markers on CC lines are pretty hard to find yet.

However, no standard C-C cable has all 24 wires. At least the USB 2.0 D+/D- wires have only one pair of them across the cable, see this assembly table from Type-C specifications,

[image]

So, the standard C-C cables have at most 22 wires.

More, if someone wants to use the Type-C connector as a nice generic 24-pin connector for arbitrary set of signals, they would need to make their own cable assembly. The reason is that standard USB cables have 5 pairs of cable wires tightly coupled/twisted to form differential pair, and can't be used for individual signals due to horrible cross-talk.

ADDITION: I'll take it a bit back. Per USB Type-C specification, ALL full-featured C-C cables are required to have eMarkers in overmolds, regardless if it is 3-A rating, or 5-A rating. So the only full-featured cables without eMarkers would be illegal, uncertifiable cables.

Answer (score 0):

Check Molex cables. Maybe they do not have any electronics inside.

http://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/ps/PS-68798-0001-001.pdf

If yes - check on alibaba who makes them and ask for the "plain" cable only. I was ordering cables for my device (I have done silly mistake when was designing the pcb) with two cables swapped. But I could order 150cables for a very good money.